# Creating Multiple Segues from TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I'm currently trying to find out how I can create different segues from each `tableviewcell` to individual view controllers.

Here's my TableViewController :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, in StoryBoard init segues based on your demand. Then, code like below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showA", sender: indexPath.row)
    }else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showB", sender: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```